# Change Text Size of UISegmentedControl in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change font size of UISegmentedControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280391/change-font-size-of-uisegmentedcontrol)
>   [how to change the font size of UISegmentedControl text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493801/how-to-change-the-font-size-of-uisegmentedcontrol-text)

How i can change the text size of Segmented Control ?

anyone can help me !!

Comment: Possible duplicate for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280391/change-font-size-of-uisegmentedcontrol , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493801/how-to-change-the-font-size-of-uisegmentedcontrol-text

Comment: dnt ask similar question

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> **Note:** This is only available for **iOS5+.**

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12.0f];
NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:font
                                                       forKey:UITextAttributeFont];
[segmentedControl setTitleTextAttributes:attributes 
                                forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: `UITextAttributeFont` is deprecated in iOS 7.0; instead use - `NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12.0f]};`